# NavigationView + GeometryReader views return incorrect size

Tags: swift, swiftui

For:

```
struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                GeometryReader { geometry -> Text in
                    print("geometry.size \(geometry.size)")
                    return Text("text")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

> geometry.size (0.0, 0.0)
>
> geometry.size (428.0, 749.0)

For:

```
struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry -> Text in
                print("geometry.size \(geometry.size)")
                return Text("text")
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

> geometry.size (428.0, 749.0)

Is it a bug? Is it possible to avoid such behavior?

Comment: I would assume it's not really a bug, but rather a function of NavigationView not immediately rendering its child views.  It looks like it does in fact give the correct values, but just on the 2nd pass.  Assuming that your view responds correctly to resizing anyway, is there a way to just deal with the fact that you get a zero size first?  Is it an expensive render to do?

Comment: The body computed property could be called multiple times, it depends on the internal UIKit views it represents and the dependancies. As a developer we don't have to worry too much about it

Comment: The real problem is that the view without @ObservableObject won't be updated. So, the size parameters won't be changed for this case.

Comment: If you have a specific example when the view is not updated, please add it to the question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  have you found a solution or way to force the navigationView to render correctly on the first pass?

Comment: Same issue here too

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a bug; any view has the right to reposition its subviews over its lifetime. Normally this behavior should make no difference to you, as the views will automatically get updated as the geometry changes.

However, if there is some logic you need done right when the `geometry.size` is updated to a non-zero value, you can monitor this in an `onChange(of:)` block:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        Text("text")
          .onChange(of: geometry.size) { newSize in
            if newSize != .zero { /* do something with newSize */ }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I talk more about this behavior and ways to work around it in this other [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71452608/12218938)